# Using Typeface.js within a GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, typeface.js

I am looking for some sample Java code demonstrating how to get AJAX content displayed into a custom font using Typeface.js within a GWT app.
I have tried a little bit by calling the following native function

```
    native void Typeface_renderDocument() /*-{ 
        $wnd._typeface_js.renderDocument();
    }-*/;
```

- after having filled the relevant widget with the AJAX content, and
- after calling the following function on the widget :

  ```
  void applyTypeface(Widget widget) {
      widget.addStyleName("typeface-js");
      widget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontFamily", "Helvetiker");
      Typeface_renderDocument();
  }
  ```

...where Helvetiker is a custom font (actually available from Typeface.js fonts page (http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html).
But the above attempt didn't work.

Any suggestions are very welcome, I am bit stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

A guess, but try running Typeface_renderDocument() in a [DeferredCommand](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/DeferredCommand.html) -- perhaps those style changes aren't visible in the DOM at the point that the JS executes.